# iTunes connect - stuck in infinite for Add New App

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to "Add New App" in my iTunes Connect site. This brings me to Agreement Update (mentioning the "The revenue share for the iAd Network is now 70% to the Developer.") Whatever, we don't want ads in our app so I click Continue. Then get to Manage Apps page. I click "Add New App" and the loop continues.

I think I'm going out of my mind. Can anyone else confirm this is the case and there is a bug on the connect site, or is there something obvious here I'm not getting? Is there a place Apple would post that they are resolving a bug with iTunes Connect?

Thanks!

Comment: what is it with apple and infinite loops...

Comment: @user1020317 nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that it's working right now, but I actually added d a new app last night and it was slightly buggy/slow... But, I kept trying and it worked.

I would suggest trying again in a few hours or tomorrow... Bugs will be bugs and only Apple can fix them, so don't drive yourself crazy :)

NOTE: I'm not sure if this should be here... This is more for programming questions... I may be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to add my first app ever, except the Agreement update was about some Brazilian music contract. This happened 28 days before my developer program expired, so I renewed the program and entered the activation code sent to me by mail and suddenly I could add a new app.

**Key points:**

- My Developer Program was **NOT** expired
- After renewal and payment it still didn't work
- It worked immediately after activation (activation code sent by mail)